# Skype 4.3 on Ubuntu

Tags: skype

I have recently started using Ubuntu and I think it's better than Windows. The only problem is Skype, whenever I have to do a group video call or group screen sharing I still have to revert to Windows. My question is why does Ubuntu not support the latest version of Skype? Thanks for any help!

I guess my query is being wrongly interpreted. I already have Skype installed, the thing is there is no possible option for me to do group video call or group screen share. The interface itself resembles the times when Skype was newly born. While on Windows, Skype's latest version is around 6.(something), here it's only 4.3. In Windows group video call is now free on Skype, here I can't even do video call! I think this is a major drawback for an otherwise so good OS! Is there anything that can be done about it?

Comment: Hmm, isn't Skype 4.3 already available in Linux? For Ubuntu you just have to run this from the terminal `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ trusty partner" && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype`. You can do it from the GUI too I think.

Comment: I have the same problem, can't do screenshare in a group call. Did you found some solution?