# Unable to do group video call and group screen share using Skype 4.3

Tags: skype

For those who duplicated my previous question - [Skype 4.3 on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529607/skype-4-3-on-ubuntu); am NOT asking how to install Skype for God's sake!!

The question was rather - I already have Skype installed, the thing is there is no possible option for me to do group video call or group screen share. The interface itself resembles the times when Skype was newly born. While on Windows, Skype's latest version is around 6.(something), here it's only 4.3. In Windows group video call is now free on Skype, here I can't even do video call! I think this is a major drawback for an otherwise so good OS! Is there anything that can be done about it?

Thanks for any help!

For those who don't have an answer for me, I still thank you for at least *understanding* my question!!

Have a good day!

Comment: I am also struggling on this... I had to change to windows forcibly because I have to participate in client calls in group... :(  I am still waiting for a solution for this.  I even tried to downgrade to old versions... Sill no luck.

Comment: I am still waiting for the solution.  Any solution???

Comment: Ubuntu is such a good OS. After Skype is bought by Microsoft, they are deliberately doing these things in Ubuntu I guess.

Answer (score 20):

Skype does not support those features right now on Linux.  I emailed Microsoft a couple weeks ago, on this very issue, and they have said that Linux Skype does not support those features at this time.

There are numerous Skype community forum threads on this, and it appears that those features are available on Windows but not Linux.

---

**As of October 23rd, 2015, when I last tested this**, group video calling (aka "Video Conference Calls") are not supported still.  Group voice communications are still possible, but not video communications in a group chat on Skype.  Screen sharing is also not supported still either.

Comment: Skype for Linux should allow you to make group video calls: https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA194/can-i-make-conference-calls-with-skype-for-linux?q=screen+sharing+linux No group screen sharing though.

Comment: @user2707671: That support page is talking about conference calls, but does not mention video. It indeed appears that group video calls are not supported. Do you have a different experience?

Comment: Confirmed group video calls are still not supported.  Three days ago.

Answer (score 1):

As said by Thomas W.'s answer, video conferencing/group video call is unsupported on Skype for Linux.

Video conferencing works on Skype for Windows. [You can install this on Ubuntu using PlayOnLinux/Wine](https://askubuntu.com/a/722140/172367), but it requires some fiddling...