# skype conference call problem

Tags: 14.04, skype, webcam

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit version. I have installed Skype 4.3.0.37. I can call anyone. But when I try for conference call, my video device does not work and my friends on the call can see that my skype is not upgraded to allow conference call. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried this:https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA194/can-i-make-conference-calls-with-skype-for-linux ?

Comment: yes, I have tried this and I can make conference calls too, but my webcam do not work then.@Jos

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to do group video call and group screen share using Skype 4.3](http://askubuntu.com/questions/534186/unable-to-do-group-video-call-and-group-screen-share-using-skype-4-3)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you hit [bug #1372846](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1372846). Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install skype-bin
```

Comment: It did not work.It shows:
Package skype-bin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  skype

E: Package 'skype-bin' has no installation candidate

@GunnarHj

Comment: @AmartyaRej: Ok.. I assumed that you had installed Skype from the Canonical Partner repository in the Ubuntu archive, but considering what you now say, I suppose that you installed it from the skype.com web site. If so, you can disregard my answer above.

Comment: Yes, I downloaded it from the skype.com @gunnarhj

Answer (score 0):

[Video conferencing (group call with video) is unsupported on Skype for Linux](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10613/what-do-i-need-to-make-a-group-video-call).

Video conferencing works on Skype for Windows. [You can install this on Ubuntu using PlayOnLinux/Wine](https://askubuntu.com/a/722140/172367), but it requires some fiddling...