# Skype for Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, skype

I have little problem with my skype client (Xubuntu 16.04). On skype.com we can download skype but for Ubuntu 12.04 or 10.04. My system version is not available but ok, I just downloaded version 12.04. Installed, all works good but I couldn't see my conference group. I have two system and on Windows everything work good. I thought it's wrong version so I removed and installed skype by command line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```

Skype was well installed but problem returned with first start the application. Again I don't see my conference groups. My friend tell me: "You are in group", when I'am on Windows and start skype, yes I'am on group but Linux client don't show me this group. Why?! It's an application error?

Comment: Groups are not supported in the linux version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to do group video call and group screen share using Skype 4.3](http://askubuntu.com/questions/534186/unable-to-do-group-video-call-and-group-screen-share-using-skype-4-3)

Comment: @Pilot6 what do you mean "not supported" ? I had Xubuntu 14.04 and installed Skype for Ubuntu 12.04 and all works good. I had access to conferences groups. When I upgrade system just lost this access. It's ridiculous...

Comment: Skype being a Micro$oft product, you cannot expect them to have the latest, full feature product for Linux. This way they can deter users from using Linux (by annoying them, like they have with you) and force them to use Windows instead. You will have to wait for a better linux version. In any case, have you tried using Skype via Wine? That should work without a problem.

Comment: Skype was well installed but problem returned with first start the application. Again I don't see my conference groups. My friend tell me: "You are in group", when I'am on Windows and start skype, yes I'am on group but Linux client don't show me this group. Why?! It's an application error?